# Float left & right divs: I want to make it more responsive

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 2 divs: wide on left and sidebar on right. I want to make it more responsive (on lower-width screens: the left panel should get thinner but sidebar should be the same width, but **it should NOT go under wide panel**). How to fix this code?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w05y4vtg/).

HTML CODE:

```
<section >

        <div class='post' id="post-8">
      <div class='post-title'><a href="http://localhost/?p=8" title="Permalink to Lifestype post 1 Lifestype post 1" rel="bookmark">Lifestype post 1 Lifestype post 1</a></div>
      <div class='post-subtitle'>
        <div class='added-by'>BY <SPAN class='blue'>Admin</SPAN></div>
        <div class='added-at'><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXX/images/icon-clock.png" style="width:12px; margin-right:5px;" >Tuesday, December 2, 2014</div>
      </div>
      <div class='post-body'>            

                    <p>lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1 lifestype post 1</p>
<div class="addtoany_share_save_container addtoany_content_bottom"><div class="a2a_kit addtoany_list a2a_target" id="wpa2a_1"><a class="a2a_button_facebook" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/facebook?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D8&amp;linkname=Lifestype%20post%201%20Lifestype%20post%201" title="Facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/facebook.png" width="" height="" alt="Facebook"/></a><a class="a2a_button_twitter" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/twitter?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D8&amp;linkname=Lifestype%20post%201%20Lifestype%20post%201" title="Twitter" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/twitter.png" width="" height="" alt="Twitter"/></a><a class="a2a_button_google_plus" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/google_plus?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D8&amp;linkname=Lifestype%20post%201%20Lifestype%20post%201" title="Google+" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/google_plus.png" width="" height="" alt="Google+"/></a><a class="a2a_button_linkedin" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/linkedin?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D8&amp;linkname=Lifestype%20post%201%20Lifestype%20post%201" title="LinkedIn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXXX/images/linkedin.png" width="" height="" alt="LinkedIn"/></a><a class="a2a_dd addtoany_share_save" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share_save"></a>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
wpa2a.script_load();
//--></script>
</div></div>                    

      </div>
        </div>




        <div class='post' id="post-4">
      <div class='post-title'><a href="http://localhost/?p=4" title="Permalink to Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel" rel="bookmark">Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel  Post 2 by pawel</a></div>
      <div class='post-subtitle'>
        <div class='added-by'>BY <SPAN class='blue'>Admin</SPAN></div>
        <div class='added-at'><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/icon-clock.png" style="width:12px; margin-right:5px;" >Tuesday, December 2, 2014</div>
      </div>
      <div class='post-body'>            

                    <p>Post 2 by pawel</p>
<p>Post 2 by pawel</p>
<p>Post 2 by pawel</p>
<div class="addtoany_share_save_container addtoany_content_bottom"><div class="a2a_kit addtoany_list a2a_target" id="wpa2a_3"><a class="a2a_button_facebook" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/facebook?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D4&amp;linkname=Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel" title="Facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/facebook.png" width="" height="" alt="Facebook"/></a><a class="a2a_button_twitter" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/twitter?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D4&amp;linkname=Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel" title="Twitter" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/twitter.png" width="" height="" alt="Twitter"/></a><a class="a2a_button_google_plus" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/google_plus?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D4&amp;linkname=Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel" title="Google+" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/google_plus.png" width="" height="" alt="Google+"/></a><a class="a2a_button_linkedin" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/linkedin?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Fp%3D4&amp;linkname=Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel%20%20Post%202%20by%20pawel" title="LinkedIn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXXX/images/linkedin.png" width="" height="" alt="LinkedIn"/></a><a class="a2a_dd addtoany_share_save" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share_save"></a></div></div>                  

      </div>
        </div>





            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"></div>
                <div class="nav-next"></div>
            </div>

</section>


        <aside>
              <div class="subsection-title">Search</div>

                <form id="searchform" method="get" action="http://localhost">
                    <div class="input-group" style='width: 100%;'>  
                      <input id="s" name="s" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/images/icon-search.png" class="image-icon"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>

        <div class="ruler">
          <hr class="ribbon"></hr>
        </div>                              


                <div id="tptn_related" class="tptn_posts "><h3>Popular Posts</h3><ul><li><span class="tptn_after_thumb"><a href="http://localhost/?p=8" rel="bookmark"  class="tptn_link"><span class="tptn_title">Lifestype post 1 Lifestype post 1</span></a> <span class="tptn_list_count">(4)</span></span></li></ul></div>.



                    <!--
                    <div class="ruler">
                        <hr class="ribbon"></hr>
                    </div>
                --> 
                    <div class="subsection-title">Subscribe</div>

                <form id="searchform" method="get" action="http://localhost">
                    <div class="input-group">   
                        <input name="s" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email ..."  disabled >
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXXX/images/icon-rss.png" class="image-icon"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>         

                <div class="ruler">
          <hr class="ribbon"></hr>
        </div>

                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/XXXXXX/images/social-image.png" width="100%" />
                    </div>                              
                    <div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; padding: 10px; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
                        <p class="image-title white">XXXXXX</p>
                        <p class="image-text white">
                            http://www.XXXXX.com is new website that entirely helps you get a tax refund. The averige employyee is due €880 a year in over-paid tax.
                        </p>
                        <p class="image-text white">
                            See what you are due!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; padding: 10px; top: 180px; left: 10px;">                           
                        <div style="min-height:33px;" class="really_simple_share really_simple_share_button robots-nocontent snap_nopreview"><div class="really_simple_share_facebook_like" style="width:100px;"><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.XXXXX.com" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" ></div></div><div class="really_simple_share_twitter" style="width:100px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal"  data-text="XXXXXX" data-url="https://www.XXXXXX.com"  data-via=""   ></a></div></div>
        <div class="really_simple_share_clearfix"></div>                    </div>
                </div>      
        </aside>
```

CSS code:

```
section {
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 700px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background-color: red; }

aside {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 36%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: `aside` needs to be 250px wide at all times?

Comment: suppose, yes:) I know that it wont work perfectly on small screens, but .. suppose YES for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
body {
  margin:0; padding:0;}

section {
  display: block;
  margin:6px 262px 0 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  max-width: 700px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red; }

aside {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
```

I've made a number of changes to your styles.

Namely:

1) The `<section>` still has a max-width, but it no longer has a specified width. Instead, on any page-width less than `700px`, its width is always automatically re-calculated as 100% of the width of the page minus left and right margins.

2) The `<section>` no longer has a `float:left;` property. The width of its left and right margins determine its position on the page.

3) The `<aside>` no longer has a `float:right;` property. Instead, it has a `position:absolute;` of `top:0; right:0;` and margins to offset it from that position.

4) I have replaced the dynamic-width padding (`padding-right: 2%;`) with a fixed-width padding of `6px`. In fact, all `margins` and all `paddings` in both `<section>` and `<aside>` are now a fixed width of `6px`.

Comment: Let me put it into whole page. It seems to work. I just dont need abolutes, they behaves strangely :).

Comment: In this case, `{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}` simply pins the `<aside>` to the top right corner of the page.